# C# Ignoring Exception

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I have a button which calls the method "refresh", when clicking the button without selecting a path with another button, my method calls an exception. How can I ignore this exception without doing anything? I know that I can ignore exceptions like this:

```
 try
  {
   blah
  }
 catch (Exception e)
  {
   <nothing here>
  }
```

My case looks like this:

```
void refresh() //gets called by button
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();

            //will cause exception
            var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(objDialog.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

            foreach (string file in files)
            {
               xxx
            }
            xxx
            xxx
        }
```

The line

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(objDialog.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

throws an invalid path exception. If I put my code into try-catch,

```
files
```

in             `foreach (string file in files)` can't be found in further code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: By leaving the code-bnlock empty? `catch { }`.However you should do that only in rare cases, swollowing exceptions is considered a really bad thing. However I doubt an `InvalidPathException` should be swaalowed at all. Instead try to **avoid** that exception by checking if the file exists.

Comment: Not that you could do anything with *files* anyway.

Comment: The program opens a folder, by clicking on radio boxes you can filter for specific files. When the user filters before selecting a folder (which is not a bad thing) the exceptions will pop up. I need to use this method everytime the user updates the filter in order to update the listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the SelectedPath has a value:

```
void refresh() //gets called by button
{
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objDialog.SelectedPath))
    {
        listBox1.Items.Clear();

        //will cause exception
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(objDialog.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (string file in files)
        {
           xxx
        }
        xxx
        xxx
    }
}
```

Comment: "when clicking the button without selecting a path with another button" seems to indicate so

Comment: Thank you for spending time on this simple question. You helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't swallow exceptions. They usually contain information on what exactly went wrong. Instead of *handling* the exception in a really weird way, you should *avoid* it in the first place by checking if the directory exists:

```
void refresh() //gets called by button
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(objDialog.SelectedPath) && Directory.Exists(objDialog.SelectedPath))
    {
        var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(objDialog.SelectedPath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```